# Subversion Merge Access Rights

Tags: svn, merge

I need to limit access to merge changes into the trunk to specific individuals.  Is there any way to limit merge rights on specific folders in subversion?  I don't want to block merging from branch to branch, only into the trunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you make the trunk read-only for those specific people, using Subversion's access control mechanisms?

In your [`svnaccess`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) file:

```
[/MyProject/trunk]
me = rw
albert = r
bernard = r
chris = rw
```

would allow you and Chris to make changes (including merges) to the trunk of "MyProject", while only giving read permissions to Albert and Bernard.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no such thing as "merge rights", only read and write permissions. And merging is actually a write operation, you have to give write permission to specific folders ('trunk' in you case) only to those you want to.

Pleas read ["Path-Based Authorization"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) for details.

Comment: Agree. A "merge" is really an Update (read from repo), followed by some edits (combining your code), followed by a commit.  That commit looks like any other.